# Quick sort doesn't sort every time

Tags: c, quicksort

I've a problem with my Quicksort. For some values it works but for other it doesn't. For example when the first value is smaller than the last it doesn't work. I don't know what is wrong. This is code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define lenght_max 1000000
int x;
int tablica[lenght_max];
int q;

int Partition(left, right) {

    int tmp;
    int i;
    int j;

    i = -1;
    j = 0;

    x = tablica[right];
    i = left - 1;

    for(j = left; j < right; j++){
      if(tablica[j] <= x) {
        i++;
        tmp = tablica[i];
        tablica[i] = tablica[j];
        tablica[j] = tmp;
      }
    }

    return i + 1;
}

void Quicksort(left, right) {    
    if(left < right){ 
      q = Partition(left, right);
      Quicksort(left , q - 1);
      Quicksort(q + 1, right);
    }
}

int main(void) {

  int i;
  int temporary;
  int left;
  int right;

  printf("Witaj uzytkowniku. To jest program preferujacy sortowanie szybkie - quicksort.\n");
  printf("Podaj, ile liczb chcialbys posortowac: ");
  scanf("%i", &temporary);

  printf("Podaj liczby do sortowania: \n");

  for(i = 0; i < temporary; i++)
    scanf("%d", &tablica[i]);

    left = 0;
    right = temporary - 1;
    x = temporary / 2;

  Quicksort(left, right);

  printf("\nPROCES:\n");

  for(i = 0; i < temporary; i++)
    printf("%d\n", tablica[i]);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `Partition()` method is suspecious. You set the pivot as the `r+1` element (remember arrays are starting from 0), and iterate from `p` to `r` *exclusive*. This usually indicates a bug, but the unfamiliar variable names (why don't use english? It's pretty much the convention...) making it very hard to follow.

Comment: so r is the last element and p is first element in table

Comment: Ok, I see what you did there now, it seems fine from second look. Still, better translate the variable names to english - it will be easier for everyone to follow and you will likely get better answers.

Comment: i translated my code to English names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I didn't overlook the problem, it seems to me that you forgot to swap the pivot with the first element grater than the pivot at the end of `Partition`. The fix should be as simple as adding:

```
    tmp            = tablica[i+1];
    tablica[i+1]   = tablica[right];
    tablica[right] = tmp;
```

before the `return i + 1;` statement inside `Partition`.

Comment: @henio180 I have seen that you have never accepted an answer to any of your questions. Assuming that was not on purpose, please read the following [part](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) of the faq, which in the end explains how to deal with useful answers. Then I suggest you to go back and accept the most useful answers from your previous questions.